# El operador no existe: bigint ~~ unknown Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**En el controlador:**

```
@sales = Sale.where("id like ?", "%#{sales_number}%")
```

**La url que solicito**

```
http://localhost:3000/sales/sales/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sales_number=1000&button=
```

**El error**

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  el operador no existe: bigint ~~ unknown
LINE 1: SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE (id like '%1000%')
                                                ^
```

**HINT**

```
Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos.
    : SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE (id like '%1000%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solución:

```
@sales = Sale.where("CAST(id AS TEXT) ILIKE ?", "%#{sales_number}%")
```